Rotating triangle

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,pdftex]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}


\newcounter{density}
\setcounter{density}{20}
 
\newcommand{\trianglee}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]
        \def\couleur{#2}
        \path[coordinate] (-1,0) coordinate(A)  % Сдвигаем точку A влево на 1
                    ++(0:6cm) coordinate(B)
                    ++(120:6cm) coordinate(C);
        \pgfmathsetcounter{density}{20}
        \setcounter{density}{\thedensity}
        \draw[fill=\couleur!\thedensity] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
    
        \foreach \x in {1,...,40}{%
            \pgfmathsetcounter{density}{\thedensity + 7} 
            \setcounter{density}{\thedensity}
            \path[coordinate] (A) -- (B) coordinate[pos=.1](A)
                                    -- (C) coordinate[pos=.1](B)
                                    -- (A) coordinate[pos=.1](C);
            \draw[fill=\couleur!\thedensity] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }


\begin{document}

\trianglee{1}{Violet}

\end{document}

I want to create a rotated triangle for my book but the center of the triangle is shifted somehow. How to fix it?

You're overwriting coordinate A with the new position but want to use the previous later. Replace (A) in the \path with cycle and you don't need an extra coordinate.

@Qrrbrbirlbel yeah, You are right :), thanks

Thanks to @Qrrbrbirlbel comment, now it fine. Also you can findthe full code and other figures in capter 7.15 here
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,pdftex]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}


\newcounter{density}
\setcounter{density}{20}
 
\newcommand{\trianglee}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]
        \def\couleur{#2}
        \path[coordinate] (-1,0) coordinate(A)  % Сдвигаем точку A влево на 1
                    ++(0:6cm) coordinate(B)
                    ++(120:6cm) coordinate(C);
        \pgfmathsetcounter{density}{20}
        \setcounter{density}{\thedensity}
        \draw[fill=\couleur!\thedensity] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
    
        \foreach \x in {1,...,40}{%
            \pgfmathsetcounter{density}{\thedensity + 7} 
            \setcounter{density}{\thedensity}
            \path[coordinate] (A) -- (B) coordinate[pos=.1](A)
                                    -- (C) coordinate[pos=.1](B)
                                    -- cycle coordinate[pos=.1](C);
            \draw[fill=\couleur!\thedensity] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }


\begin{document}

\trianglee{1}{Violet}

\end{document}

